# Spring and Hibernate 4 not working with Tomcat 6 security enabled

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat6

Spring and Hibernate 4 application is deployed and run successfully on Tomcat 6. But, when starting Tomcat 6 with a security manager by below command:

```
apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin>catalina start -security
```

Tomcat 6 throws AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)

One solution could be to change catalina.policy permissions. But my app is deployed on 3rd party Tomcat 6 server and don't have rights to change catalina.policy.

Spring-Hibernate 4 integration code:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
    p:packagesToScan="com.vikas.domain" p:namingStrategy-ref="namingStrategy" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

Please find below error stacktrace on running with security manager:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkCreateClassLoader(SecurityManager.java:594)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.<init>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.<init>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.<init>(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
```

How could I fix the exception without changing catalina.policy or any other Tomcat server changes?

Comment: And how is this related to Spring Security?! The only thing I see in the stacktrace is that the component-scan isn't allowed to use reflection on the controllers. Which has nothing to do with Spring Security. The only way to fix the exception for this particular case is not to use component-scanning but to declare all the beans.

Comment: Thanks Deinum for pointing out that. I have mistakenly given wrong exception trace. After further looking into the exception trace of my application, I have figured out the exception is related to Hibernate not Spring Security. Exception is AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader). I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: On downgrading from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 3, getting AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader) . setContextClassLoader and createClassLoader permissions are not granted by the server. In that case, do I need to switch to some other ORM. Or, is there any workaround with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of running Tomcat with *security manager* is to give it some security and the only way to override the security is by either editing the security policy to cover your needs or to have it run without *security manager*.  My suggestion is to ask the appropriate customer support team who are in charge of this 3rd party Tomcat server to make the necessary changes on your behalf.